# <br/> tag in HTML title breaks pdfmake export in jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables, pdfmake

I am trying to format how the data is displayed in a jquery DataTable.

If the text is long, I truncate it like below:

```
{
"data": "col1", "render": function (data, type, row) {
        if (type === 'display' && data != null) {
              data = data.replace(/<(?:.|\\n)*?>/gm, '');
              data = data.split("; ").join("<br/>");
                  if (data.length > 85) {

                      return '<span class=\"show-ellipsis\" title="'+data+'">' + data.substr(0, 85) + '</span><span class=\"no-show\">' + data.substr(85) + '</span>';
                  } else {
                      return data;
                  }
        } else {
           return data;
        }
   }
},
```

and use the following CSS alongside jquery UI tooltip.

***CSS***

```
 span.no-show {
    display: none;
}

span.show-ellipsis:after {
    content: "...";
}
```

---

***jQuery UI tooltip***

```
<script>
$(function () {
    $(document).tooltip({
        items: 'span.show-ellipsis',
        content: function () {
            return $(this).attr('title');
        },
        position: {
            my: "center bottom",
            at: "center top-10",
            collision: "flip",
            using: function (position, feedback) {
                $(this).addClass(feedback.vertical)
                    .css(position);
            }
        }

    });

});
```

---

This way it appears nicely in the DataTable,

[image: datatable]

The screenshot above had `<hr>` instead of `<br/>` tag in replace method, but the behavior remains the same. It works fine if I replace with `\n`. When I try to export the pdf, data gets repeated. In particular the data.substr(85) part.

[image: pdf export]

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you

Comment: It's like your exported PDF does not take the CSS in consideration no?

Comment: Yes the `display: none` part. But why does it take it into consideration when the method is called like this `data = data.split("; ").join("\n"); ?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, in your button

```
                extend: 'pdfHtml5',
                exportOptions: {
                    orthogonal: 'export',
                }
```

in your columns :

```
        render: function (data, type, row) {
        return type === 'export' ? row.Descripcion: "";
     }
```